# How to use image from Apache HTTP server?

Tags: apache, tomcat8, httpserver, static-content

I create static web project from Eclipse IDE and run with [Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](http://webauth.stanford.edu/manual/platform/windows.html). I can open it from my browser as below screenshoot.

[image]

Next , I create a dynamic web project from eclipse IDE and use image from my HTTP server as

```
<img  width="150px" height="150px" src="localhost:122/static-project/images/avatar.png">
```

And then run with apache Tomcat8 server.But the image is not show, when I inspect with firebug plugin there has no 404 error for image. I copied `src` value of image and open with new tab of browser , it is ok. Image show in new tab correctly. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be corrected as :

`<img  width="150px" height="150px" src="http://localhost:122/static-project/images/avatar.png">`

Comment: OMG ! It is work ... :). Thank you I forgot to add `http://` . Ahh.... It takes long time. Thank you sir you save my life.